# Do I always need to run a function that works like a class in javascript (ES5)?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

I was looking the playground of [Typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html) and saw this class declaration:

```
class Greeter {
   greeting: string;
   constructor(message: string) {
       this.greeting = message;
   }
   greet() {
       return "Hello, " + this.greeting;
   }
}
```

converted to this ES5 code:

```
var Greeter = (function () {
   function Greeter(message) {
       this.greeting = message;
   }
   Greeter.prototype.greet = function () {
       return "Hello, " + this.greeting;
   };
   return Greeter;
}());
```

In EcmaScript5 Do I always need to run a function that works *like* a class? or it is because the `protoype.greet` is inside that initial anonymous function?

Comment: no, but it's a good idea to encapsulate the prototype object just to make it easier to read, and you can have private state and helpers if they are required.

Comment: No. You don't need to do use an IIFE at all even if you fiddle with the prototype of the constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes):

> JavaScript classes introduced in ECMAScript 6 are syntactical sugar over JavaScript's existing prototype-based inheritance. The class syntax is not introducing a new object-oriented inheritance model to JavaScript. JavaScript classes provide a much simpler and clearer syntax to create objects and deal with inheritance.

So yes. You always need to run a function that works like a class.

Comment: I think they are talking about the closure around the es5 class